# after socket.accept() statement no other statement is executing how to make accept by server?

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

the code snippet i'm trying to execute

```
 ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(7777);  


          Socket socket=ss.accept();

          System.out.println("Connection:"+socket.isConnected());
```

i'm trying to get data from another program to this class i'm using same port for Socket,ServerSocket.

another program code

```
Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",7777);      
  fileData.append(LineNumber + ": " + inputLine + "\n");//fileData is jtext area
            DataOutputStream dos4=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dos4.writeUTF(LineNumber + ": " + inputLine + "\n");

            dos4.close();
            socket.close();
```

Comment: Come on. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--) for this method: `Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. **The method blocks until a connection is made.**`

Comment: Can you show us the code for the other program, making the connection?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose has answered your question.

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work, provided you start your server first. Try starting your server, then use telnet to connect to it: "telnet localhost 7777". See whether the server accepts the connection.

Comment: I got it  @Seelenvirtuose but how to make accept() method release the block?

Comment: @LogicSystemsJava You can't. Maybe you want to do some parallel processing. This is usually done with threads. Start one thread that listens for incoming connections. This thread blocks at the `accept` method, but other threads are still doing their work.

Comment: In addition to everything you've already been told, testing `Socket.isConnected()` on a `Socket` you've just acquired from `ServerSocket.accept()` is completely futile. It will never be false.

Comment: why it is not accepting connection? i'm not getting through your comments does anybody know or not?

Comment: The answer has been provided by @Seelenvirtuose, even though comments are not required to be answers.

Comment: @LogicSystemsJava There seems to be shift in your question. You first asked why "no other statement is executing" after the `ss.accept()` call. I explained it by referencing the documentation. Your added client code and your further comments seem to describe that you have problems getting a connection from the client to the server. If so, then your question is very unclear. Please rephrase your question to make it clear. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: thanks for help @Seelenvirtuose i have asked two questions till now one is why other statements not executing after i came to know that the reason is .accept method then My 2nd question is why it's not accepting the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to communicate through socket here one example which will guide you about socket programming

it will listen to client

```
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);  
Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection   
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
String  str=dis.readUTF();  
System.out.println("message= "+str);  
dis.close();
```

Here is client code who will write to server

```
Socket s=new Socket("localhost",6666);  
DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
dout.close();
```